# Why can't i get the container slide to respond to the image only

Tags: html, css

I've making an image and a slide and everything seems to work the way I want it, but the left side reacts when I haven't even reached the image. I've played with if for a while but as it is I can't figure out why.
not to mention I can't find the words but I haven't worked on that part much.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 225px;
  right: -50%;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 137%;
  height: 0%;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.actives_center_image_1{
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 30%;
 bottom: 40px;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/16026669/got_lede_image.jpg" class="actives_center_image_1"> 
    <div class="overlay">
   <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have defined the hover for the container and your image has left a margin. Either remover the margin or define hover for the image because of

```css
.actives_center_image_1{
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 30%;
 bottom: 40px;
 display: block;
}
```

.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 225px;
  right: -50%;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 137%;
  height: 0%;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.actives_center_image_1{
 position: relative;
  
 bottom: 40px;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/16026669/got_lede_image.jpg" class="actives_center_image_1"> 
    <div class="overlay">
   <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Or you can define another container and put it inside the main one and do the same thing.

Comment: Margin left is how I center the image